# Multiple sort by columns in query

Tags: sql, database, oracle, datetime, timestamp

I have this query:

```
SELECT T1.* 
FROM TABLE1 
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T2.ID = T1.ID
ORDER BY T1.DATE DESC, T2.DATE DESC;
```

In the above query, I use multiple sort columns from different tables. Both order by columns are of timestamp datatype. My requirement is: I need to sort the query which is higher date and time(latest). For example If T1.DATE is latest then I need to sort the query based on T1.DATE else need to sort based on T2.DATE.

How can I handle this in the `ORDER BY` clause?

Similarly I might have TABLE3 also. If I join that table, I must sort by TABLE3's DATE also. Does anyone have any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare the date columns using `greatest()` which returns the largest value of all the parameters per row:

```
SELECT T1.* FROM TABLE1 
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T3 ON T2.ID = T3.ID
ORDER BY greatest(T1.DATE, T2.DATE, T3.DATE) DESC;
```

Comment: Beware nulls. If there is any null in the GREATEST list, you get a null result. Try greatest (nvl(t1.date,'date '1800-01-01'), nvl(t2.date, date '1800-01-01'), nvl(t3.date,date '1800-01-01'))

Comment: As you said, need to handle null condition too. Thanks